# Add Bookmark functionality to bar button item

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, toolbar, bookmarks

I am having a toolbar which consists of many Bar Button item. Among that I have kept one as the Bookmark button. Now I want to add the Bookmark functionality to that Bar Button Item. How this can be done ? Can anyone suggest me ?

EDITED:

I need to open Bookmarks menu the same way it is opening in the Safari Browser. I am having toolbar with has Bookmarks Bar Button Item

Comment: Your problem is not very well described. I am sure you know that you can trigger an action by a button; so the action can do your "bookmark functionality". What exactly is your problem?

Comment: I have edited my question please check it

Comment: Are you asking how to display the user interface component called a Popover?  Start with the [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerPGforiOSLegacy/iPadControllers/iPadControllers.html).

Comment: @user562100 It is still hard to say, where your problem is. Do you want to know how to programm the GUI? How to store data (see answer by Desai Ajay)? How to get your URL? Give us more hints, or better show some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have done before bookmark in my app. i stored the data in sqlite using fmdb because it became easy to add and  delete the bookmark if we store it in database.

Comment: Thanks for replying .So,we Can Store it in some place like array or the DB and we have to retrieve it. Am i Right? Is there any other way ?

Comment: i think db is right approach because ones user bookmark something than if he will close the app than it will contain that record in db and u can revive it from there but array can't do that.